# What happens to encrypted drives if the computer is damaged?

Tags: bitlocker

I bitlock all of my hard drive except for the C drive.

What happens if my computer malfunctions and I have to move the drive to another computer?

Will all of my encrypted drive be useless?

Will it be okay as long as I know the password for those drives?

What about the C drive? Will it be any different? That's because the C drive, which is the boot drive, is different. For example, in my computer where the C drive is bitlocked, I do not set any password to the C drive.

Comment: Unless you back up the keys, yes, they will be useless.

Comment: This is what backups are for.  Just because the storage device encrypts the data, does not mean, you can skip doing backups on your data.  You can encrypt those backups, most good storage device image software suites, support encrypting the image that is created.  Its important to point out you should just backup the files not do a sector-by-sector image for a variety of reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Source [BitLocker Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831507.aspx)

**Can I access my BitLocker-protected drive if I insert the hard disk into a different computer?**

> Yes, if the drive is a data drive, you can unlock it from the BitLocker Drive Encryption Control Panel item just as you would any other data drive by using a password or smart card. If the data drive was configured for automatic unlock only, you will have to unlock it by using the recovery key. If it is an operating system drive mounted on another computer running Windows 7 or later, the encrypted hard disk can be unlocked by a data recovery agent (if one was configured) or it can be unlocked by using the recovery key.
>
> Note
>
> Mounting the hard disk on another computer running Windows 8 is a quick and straightforward way to recover information from a damaged computer that has a BitLocker-protected drive on the hard disk.